# Maintain data integrity between MySQL and Redis

Tags: mysql, redis, data-integrity

I have this eCommerce application that can process orders and deduct the stock value. This is legacy code and I can not change the technology stack.

I have difficulty to manage data integrity because the order process is done through database MySQL, while the stock is saved in Redis.

Once the Order process complete successfully, then I must deduct the stock value from Redis. But if the order process is failed, then I must not do any deduction. For example:

```
Stock in Redis: 1000
Completed order: 200 (Row count in MySQL "order" table)
Expected New Stock in Redis: 800
```

The order process function basically is mixing transactions between MySQL and Redis. Pretty much like this:

```
try {
  $Mysql->beginTransaction();
  $Mysql->processOder();
  $Redis->multi();         //start redis transaction
  $Redis->deductStock();
  $Redis->exec()           //redis commit
  $Mysql->commit();        //mysql commit
} catch (Exception $e)
  $Mysql->rollback();      //mysql rollback
  $Redis->discard();       //redis rollback
}
```

I've came across several SO question and still have no sufficient answer.

With the code example above, if the Redis transaction is successful but the Mysql commit failed somehow, I should "undone" the stock deduction, right?

what if the "undone" operation also error/failed? what should I do then to keep the data between MySQL and Redis keep consistent and integrated?

Comment: You say that you can't change the tech stack, but maybe you could at least better explain how MySQL and Redis are being used here.  MySQL and Redis are not the same thing; the former is a RDBMS, used for long term storage of data, and is about 100 times slower than the latter, which is used for short term storage, but is very fast.

Comment: hi @TimBiegeleisen thank you for the comment, edited the question, trying my best, feel free to shout if anything unclear

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is that your existing approach won't guarantee consistency between two DBs, because you can not perform a 2PC (Two-Phase Commit) between two separated Data Base.
There are a bunch of patterns out there from Sagas to Event Sourcing that you can check out, but I make the long story short and try to provide something practical.
Try to store a `log` of the `order` in a separate table in your MySQL DB and insert the log into the MySQL DB inside your `try` phrase. because MySQL itself handles both actions, it is atomic.
Then write a script to process the logs periodically to update the `Redis` data and insert deduct data (maybe with a retry policy) or reverse `order` which was stored before in `MySQL` in case of failure.
Also, you can have a look at [Transactional Outbox Pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html).